# React: how to pass a object inside a child component?

Tags: reactjs, components

i really new on React and i have a problem. I have a notification system that i envelope inside a component. To this component i need to send the object that contains the message and the level of the message.

I have this component on the top level of the app. So i want that my another child components can access to this notification component.

For example, if i have a login component and the login fails, then i want to call this notification:

```
 handleSubmit(data){
    var self = this;
    //console.log(data);
    AuthService.signin(data)
    .then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function(error){

        self.props.onShowNotification({
            message: error.response.data,
            level: 'error'
        })
        console.log(error.response.data);
    })
}
```

On my Parent Component:

```
      constructor(){
    super()

    this.state = {
      notificationObject: {}
    }

    this.handleNotification = this.handleNotification.bind(this);
  }

  handleNotification(notificationObject){
    this.setState({
      notificationObject: notificationObject
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="full-height">
        {this.state.notificationObject.message && <Notifications notificationObject={this.state.notificationObject}></Notifications>}
        <Login onShowNotification={this.handleNotification}></Login>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And my Notification Component:

```
    constructor(props){
    super(props)
}


componentDidMount() {
    this._notificationSystem = this.refs.notificationSystem;
    console.log(this.props.notificationObject)
    this._notificationSystem.addNotification({
        message: this.props.notificationObject.message,
        level: this.props.notificationObject.level
    });
}

render(){
    return(
        <NotificationSystem ref="notificationSystem" />
    );
}
```

The problem is that i got this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {error}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons.

An image to see better this:

[image]

I have read a lot of other questions but none of them can help me.

Can you help me?

Comment: Could you post the `render` function in which you display the error ? This error means that you're trying to render an object which is not a basic object (string, number, etc...) or a React object.

Comment: Hi @PaulDS all the render that i use is on the post. I don't render anything directly like this: `{this.props.notficationObjet}` can you help me?

Comment: Are you using this library: https://github.com/igorprado/react-notification-system ? If so I suppose that this library expect the "message" property to be a string. Can you check that the `error.response.data` object coming from you're `AuthService` is a string ?

Comment: OMG! That's its!!! You got it my friend!! Thanks a lot! Yes.... is this library and yes... the data that i was send is another object! Please write the answer so i can pick it as correct. Once again, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in comments, the problem is due to the fact that the property `error.response.data` is not a "valid React child".
This property is passed to the NotificationSystem component (https://github.com/igorprado/react-notification-system), which may try to render it as a string.

The solution is to pass a real string instead of the `error.response.data`.